# Unable to set date field programmatically

Tags: entities, datetime

Somehow my custom fields ('datum' and 'high') are not set in the following script. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    function erstelle_kursenodes() {

$content = file_get_contents('http://www.xmlcharts.com/cache/precious-metals.php?format=json');

if(empty($content)){
    echo 'KEINE API-VERBINDUNG';
} else {
$cuobj = json_decode($content);
  // add node properties
  $newNode = (object) NULL;
  $newNode->type = 'kurs';
  $newNode->title = 'XAUUSD';
  $newNode->uid = 0;
  $newNode->created = strtotime("now");
  $newNode->changed = strtotime("now");
  $newNode->status = 1;
  $newNode->comment = 0;
  $newNode->promote = 0;
  $newNode->moderate = 0;
  $newNode->sticky = 0;
  // add fields
  $newNode->field_datum[$node->language][0]['value'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("now"));
  $newNode->field_high[$node->language][0]['value'] = number_format($cuobj->usd->gold * 31.1034768, 2, '.', '');
  // save node
  node_save($newNode);
}}
```

'datum' is a regular date field

'high' is decimal integer with two digits after a point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a format issue that you are choosing to save.

```
    $newNode->field_datum['und'][0]['value'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("now"));
//Here in place $node->language pass 'und' and then try.
//Just save a node directly from backend, let say it is saved with node id 10.

$nid = 10;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(node_load($nid)) ;
echo "</pre>";
```

Now check which format it is using to save. Pass same format once statically and then make it dynamic. Hopefully it will resolve your issue.

Comment: 'und' did the trick, i guess my fault was too much copypasting and getting blind of so many letters, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$node` isn't defined anywhere in your function, so `$node->language` will be `NULL`.

You probably meant:

```
$newNode->field_datum[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("now"));
$newNode->field_high[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = number_format($cuobj->usd->gold * 31.1034768, 2, '.', '');
```

Or to use a specific language code instead.